# Uncaught TypeError: exitFunction is not a function even though it is called successfully from another method

Tags: reactjs

Here is my React class:

```
class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // bind functions
        this._onClick = this._onClick.bind(this);
        this._onMouseMove = this._onMouseMove.bind(this);
        document.addEventListener("keydown", this._handleKeyDown);

        this._handleClick = this._handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    _handleKeyDown(e) {
        switch( e.keyCode ) {
            // If the user presses the escape key
            case 27:
                this.exitFunction(document.getElementById('test_id'));
                break;
            default: 
                break;
        }
    }

    _onClick(e) {
        // do stuff

        let cv = document.getElementById("test_id");
        this.exitFunction(cv);
    }

    exitFunction(cv) {
        console.log("in exit function");
    }
}
```

When I call this.exitFunction from the `_onClick` method, I get no errors. When I call it from `_handleKeyDown` I get an error saying:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exitFunction is not defined
>      at HTMLDocument._handleKeyDown

Is this because I added the listener to the document for the `_handleKeyDown` function, and it can't get the right context using `this.exitFunction`.

If so, how do I call `this.exitFunction()` using the right context?

**EDIT:**

I added the binding for `_handleClick` in the constructor. How come I can't add the binding after the `addEventListener` line? I get `this.exitFunction` is undefined, but if I add it before the `addEventListener` line, it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind the `this` keyword in `handleKeyDown` to your component's execution context. Otherwise, `this` will be undefined within the function.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // bind functions
    this._onClick = this._onClick.bind(this);
    this._onMouseMove = this._onMouseMove.bind(this);
    this._handleKeyDown = this._handleKeyDown.bind(this);

    document.addEventListener("keydown", this._handleKeyDown);
}
```

You can also use arrow-functions as well as SiddAjmera suggested. Arrow-functions have lexical-binding, they implicitly receive the component's execution context. Therefore you will not need them to bind each function to the constructor.

Comment: I think the error message provided in the question points to the fact that `this` will be pointing to the instance invoking the event handler. In his case the `HTMLDocument`.

Comment: Just added something to the question in the bottom "Edit" section. Your solution worked though

Comment: @Michael hmmm I'm not sure what would cause that. Does your component actually load when you define the addEventlistener before the handleClick or are you stuck on an error screen?

Comment: @Michael seems to not be giving any error here, but I would advise against using global event-listeners for this purpose and just assign one to the mark-up that you actually want to listen to: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-bush-gynn5

Answer (score 2):

Try using arrow functions instead to retain the context of `this`:

```
class Test extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this._handleKeyDown);
  }

  _handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      // If the user presses the escape key
      case 27:
        this.exitFunction(document.getElementById('test_id'));
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  _onClick = (e) => {
    // do stuff
    let cv = document.getElementById("test_id");
    this.exitFunction(cv);
  }

  exitFunction = (cv) => {
    console.log("in exit function");
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI: also these functions are assigned to each instance of the class and are not part of the class/prototype. Which is very similar what the `this binding` is doing.